# Как оставить только значения int64 в Series Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, анализ-данных

Есть ряд элементов:

```
s = pd.Series([1, 'halva', 1.10, -20])
```

Как оставить только целочисленные значения?

Нашел вот такую команду, но она для датафреймов: df.select_dtypes(include=int64)

Comment: А как быть с целыми числами представленными в виде строк?  Например , какой должен быть результат для: s = pd.Series([1, “halva”, 1.10, -20, “123”]) ?

Comment: А как быть с целыми числами представленными в виде строк?-исключать из итоговой выборки

Comment: результат для: s = pd.Series([1, “halva”, 1.10, -20, “123”])     будет  следующий [1,-20]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очевидно, как:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series([np.int64(1), 'halva', 1.10, -20])
df = pd.DataFrame(s)
df[df[0].apply(lambda el: type(el) == np.int64)]
```

Но следует быть внимательынм с типами, как сказал @MaxU

Comment: данная команда выведет целочисленные значения индексов df, т.е. просто перечислит все индексы

Comment: @pastor_bank поправил

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйтк так:

```
In [24]: res = s[s.map(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, np.integer)))]
```

результат:

```
In [25]: res
Out[25]:
0      1
3    -20
dtype: object
```

PS в функцию [isinstance(var, type)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) в качестве второго параметра можно передавать кортеж с типами данными - тогда переменная будет проверяться последовательно на переданные в кортеж типы данных.

Пример:

```
res = s[s.map(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, np.int32, int64)))]
```

Comment: Спасибо, у вас тоже рабочий код! Мне тяжело оценить простоту и логичность кода по сравнению с предложенным выше решением от @hedgehogues, лучший ответ отдал только по принципу того, что он поступил раньше